# Is it possible to use webpack dynamic imports with rails asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, code-splitting

My problem is that after the bundles are emitted by webpack, rails assets pipeline adds hashes to the file names so it's impossible to dynamically import them

My current setup is

```
import modal from "./modal"

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
 new modal().open();
}
```

While I want:

```
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
 const modal = (await import(/* webpackChunkName: "modal" */ "./modal")).default;
 new modal().open();
}
```

But in this case, a request would fire to get `dist/modal.bundle.js`, without rails hash, while its under `dist/modal.bundle-g454545g4v45geg.js`. The bundle names are resolved with `asset_path(...)` in the html,

But I don't think there is a way of telling js code what the hash is... Am I missing something? Is there **any way** to use dynamic imports with Rails Asset Pipeline?

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = [
{
    entry: {
        main_layout: "./app/assets/layouts/main_layout.ts",
        home_page: "./app/assets/pages/home/home.ts"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "app", "assets", "dist")
    },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this but the docs are clear [webpacker supports erb](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/webpacker.html#integrating-frameworks-with-webpacker).

Run `rails webpacker:install:erb`

Change your appliaction.js pack to application.js.erb
You should now be able to call `<%= asset_path("modal.bundle.js") %>` within your pack.